# R で Excel ファイルを読み込もうとすると「ファイルが見つからない」エラーになってしまう

Tags: r

openxlsxをインストールした後、サイトにあったので `read.xlsx(book1.xlsx)` を実行したのですが "ファイルが見つからない" と出ました。
book1は存在するのですが原因が分かりません。教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: "book1.xlsx" を絶対パスで指定するとどうなりますか?

Answer (score 1):

2点考えられます。
①ファイル名に""を入れていない
`read.xlsx(book1.xlsx)`ではなく`read.xlsx("book1.xlsx")`となります。
エラーを見ていると実際には""入れてるかもしれませんが...

②保存したデータが作業ディレクトリに入っていない。
まずRで`getwd()`と入力するとフォルダの場所が出てきます。
Rはそのフォルダの位置を基準にしています。

まだRに慣れてなければそのフォルダにデータを入れて試してみてください。
もし「相対パス」や「絶対パス」という意味がわかれば他のフォルダに入っていても出来ると思います。